# Accessing currentUser in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I currently have the following code in my `app.js` config which is used on secure routes:

```
var checkLoggedin = function($q, $timeout, $http, $location, $rootScope){
  // Initialize a new promise
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  // Make an AJAX call to check if the user is logged in
  $http.get('/api/loggedin').success(function(user){
    // Authenticated
    if (user !== '0')
      $rootScope.user = user; //IS THIS ADVISABLE???
      $timeout(deferred.resolve, 0);

    // Not Authenticated
    else {
      $timeout(function(){deferred.reject();}, 0);
      $location.url('/login');
    }
  });

  return deferred.promise;
};
```

The back end returns the user object.

I would like to be able to access the current user from different controllers and wondered whether I should make use of `$rootscope` (as shown above) or whether a `Service` would be the way to go.

Any code samples would be much appreciated if Service is the way forward.

Comment: This is probably a better idea http://jonsamwell.com/url-route-authorization-and-security-in-angular/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to use your user variable in the views, reading from the rootScope is fine. However, if you in a controller want to use that user for something, you can't read it directly from the rootScope, as that variable may not yet have been set by your `checkLoggedin` function.

For instance, if you have code like this in a controller

```
.controller('NavbarCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    if ($rootScope.user) {
        // do logged in stuff
    }
    //...
```

**it may fail**, as the promise has not yet set the user variable in the rootscope.

It's a bit annoying, but to guarantee that the variable always is set, one will need to reed it as a promise. So I would try to always access the logged in user through a service.

```
.service('PersonService', function ($http) {
        return {
            getCurrentUser: function() {
                return $http.get('/api/person/me', {cache: true});
                // or you can use something similar to your code above
            }
        }
    });
```

Is an example. As you can see, I have enabled cache, so multiple calls to the function will not create new calls to the back end.

Then use it like this:

```
.controller('NavbarCtrl', function ($scope, PersonService) {
    PersonService.getCurrentUser().success(function(user) {
        $scope.user = user;
        // or maybe do something else
        $scope.showButton = user.permissionLevel > 5;
    });
    // .....
```

Comment: Thanks. At the moment I only need the current user in the views so I will stick to $rootScope but your extra examples are great. I figured that as seen as I am making the call to the back-end every page load anyway to make sure they are logged in then why not use the user info that is returned.